# How To Position An Element That Appears On Top Of All Other Elements In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

No code for this one but a question. I'm trying to create a custom animation which is a stack of 3 elements that slide in from the bottom of the screen. How would I go about positioning it above all other elements so that it isn't obscured from being viewed. Initially it is positioned off the screen, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the result you want I would use Stack in combination with AnimatedPositioned widgets

```
  Stack(
      children: [
       AnimatedPositioned(
         ...
         ...
         child: YourWidget()
    
        ),
        AnimatedPositioned(
          ...
          ...
          child: YourWidget()

    ),
  ],
)
```

Read more in the docs.

[API docs about AnimatedPositioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedPositioned-class.html)

[API docs about Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

From what you said, I would suggest using a [ModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/showBottomSheet.html).

You would use it like:

```
List<BottomSheetAction> actions = [];

actions.add(BottomSheetAction(
    "My clickable Action",
    null,
    Icons.add, () {
    _actionToTrigger();
  }));

final _actionMenu = new WidgetBottomSheetMenu(
    title: 'Header',
    actions: actions);

showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (context) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(child: _actionMenu);
    });
```

The showModalBottomSheet has a

```
transitionAnimationController
```

property which you could define your custom animation with an AnimationController